# Django ManyToManyField Error when saving in admin?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

What is wrong with my code?

```
class Group(ImageModel):
     title = models.CharField(verbose_name = "Title", max_length=7)
     photos = models.ManyToManyField('Photo', related_name='+', 
                                             verbose_name=_('Photo'),
                                             null=True, blank=True)

    .....


     pid = Photo.objects.get(image = str_path)

     gid= Group.objects.get(id = self.id)       

     self.save_photos(gid, pid)

    ....


    def save_photos(self, gid, pid):
       group_photo = GroupPhotos(groupupload=gid.id,
                                        photo=pid.id
                                        )
       group_photo.save()
```

and my GroupPhotos models is:

```
class GroupPhotos(models.Model):
    groupupload = models.ForeignKey('Group')
    photo = models.ForeignKey('Photo')
    class Meta:
        db_table = u'group_photos'
```

when i want to save it from admin panel i am getting value error sth like this:

```
Cannot assign "38": "GroupPhotos.groupupload" must be a "Group" instance.
```

with `group_photo = GroupPhotos(groupupload=gid, photo=pid`) defination it is working but there is no any changes in GroupPhotos table(group_photos). printing this `print pid.id,' >>> ',gid.id` i am getting true relation...

**UPDATE:**

I have been working since morning, but no progress... i have also tried this but nothing changed:

```
pid = Photo.objects.get(image = str_path)

ger = Group.objects.get(id = self.id)
        ger.title = self.title       
        ger.save()

        ger.photos.add(pid)
```

Comment: still i havent solve the problem...

Comment: "it is working but there is no any changes in GroupPhotos table(group_photos)" - do you mean it is not saving the data?

Comment: yes @Simon it dont save any relation data...

Answer (score 4):

The error is here:

```
group_photo = GroupPhotos(groupupload=gid.id, photo=pid.id)
```

The arguments to `groupupload` and `photo` should be instances of `Group` and `Photo` respectively. Try the following:

```
group_photo = GroupPhotos(groupupload=gid, photo=pid)
```

In other words, when creating an object you need to pass arguments of the expected type and not an integer (which may be the primary key key of the desired object but it also might not, which is why you need to pass an object of the correct type).

Comment: thank you @Simeon Visser. I tried it already, but did not change anything in GroupPhotos table(group_photos)...

Comment: when i try to add this relation in admin panel, there is no error to inserting it to GroupPhotos.

Comment: Have you changed anything to the GroupPhotos table? Apart from my answer above, I don't see something that needs to be changed in your code.

Comment: no i dont change anything in GroupPhotos. it was automatically created from Group (ManyToManyField relation) and i got it with inspecdb then add into my model and only changed model name...

Comment: with `group_photo = GroupPhotos(groupupload=gid, photo=pid)` defination it is working but there is no any changes in GroupPhotos table(group_photos). printing this `print pid.id,'  >>>  ',gid.id` i am getting true relation...

Answer (score 0):

i have solved my problem with adding **through** option to my manytomanyfield:

```
photos = models.ManyToManyField('Photo', related_name='+', 
                                     verbose_name=_('Photo'),
                                     null=True, blank=True, through=GroupPhotos)
```

some info about ManyToManyField.through [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through):

> Django will automatically generate a table to manage many-to-many
>   relationships. However, if you want to manually specify the
>   intermediary table, you can use the through option to specify the
>   Django model that represents the intermediate table that you want to
>   use.
>
> The most common use for this option is when you want to associate extra data with a many-to-many relationship.